# How to prevent voltage drop when a Motor turns on?

Tags: power, current

In my arduino project I have 2 motors connected to a 9V battery ,  Motor A is switched on and Motor B is switched off, when I turn on Motor B motor A's speed slows down and When I turn motor B off motor A speed is back to previous speed.

How to prevent this behavior ? , How to keep motors running at same speed no matter other motors on or off ,

[image]

The motor i am using 
[image]

Please help. :) thanks :)

Comment: I can't see what the connection between your question and Arduinos is.

Comment: In fact ,I am doing this for a arduino project that's why I posted it here.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but that's not what your question says.  Might be worth a quick rewording so it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Could we have some specs for the motor, please?

Comment: This is a general electronics question. The solution would be the same with or without Arduino, so therefore it is a general electronics question and should be moved to the electronics stack exchange site.

Comment: Use two batteries. One for each motor. Don't connect the batteries together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look on battery as on "ideal power source" in serie with "internal resistance" (which grows when battery is more used). Then you connect the motor to the serie. The current goes thru the circuit and the voltage is divided between the internal resistance and the external resistence - the motor (the higher resistence, the bigger part of voltage is on it). So the motor gets only part of the voltage, that the battery have with anything connected.

If you add another motor paralel to previous one, the external resistence drops (to half, if the motors are the same), so the voltage for external rezistence drops as well and voltage for internal resistence increases acordingly. If the internal resistence is small (good battery with high capacity and high current possible), then the difference is small and the voltage on battery drops only a little, if the battery is weared (high internal resistence) and those motor are hungry (low resistence), then the drop of voltage is big.

So even two or three batteries in parallel may show this effect, if your motors are to take big current each. Or maybe the effect would be small enought for you to not care.

If you really need to keep the speed, then you need to compenzate for the voltage drop. Easiest way is put some DC/DC convertor/stabiliser to way to each motor separately ( be it step-up or step-down does not matter in principle) but it would take the energy from battery faster as the convertor burns some of it to heat anyway (and will cost you more), but if the battery is powerfull enought (or the convertors have wide enought range), then your motors would run the same speed regardless of thier actual count.

Answer (score 2):

You need more power.

The battery doesn't have enough power to run both motors at the same time, use 2 9v batteries in parallel.

Comment: If i Connect 2 batteries , and When motor A is on and B is off, A will run even more speed , Won't it ? , And when B is On , A will again lose speed,  Won't it ?

Comment: No - do you understand the concepts "series" and "parallel" with regard to electronics?

Comment: No , I will read about it.

Comment: @SteveJobs - http://www.zbattery.com/Connecting-Batteries-in-Series-or-Parallel this is the page I used to check I was telling you the right thing.  It explains it much better than I can.

Comment: @Matt , I read about Parallel and Serial ,and Mine is a parallel one.

Comment: @SteveJobs - I thought you said you have one battery?  Any chance of a photo of the circuit?

Comment: Yup , I have one battery I can add more batteries,  Motors are connected parallely , I will post a digram of my design

Comment: Its the batteries that need to be in parallel.  If the motors are only good for 9V stick to 9V, don't use 20.  You should see a difference in performance

Comment: Supply each motor from a separate battery. Then the voltages will be independent.

Answer (score 1):

You are reaching the current capacity of the battery you have chosen.

The generic [9 volt battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery) (about 400 to 1200mAh) is not designed to provide as much current as a [C or D size battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes) (about 4000 to 11000mAh) over the same amount of time.

This is a case were you need to specify what is good enough before making a decision.  If you are doing this empirically, simply try using enough of a larger capacity batter to develop the necessary voltage.  It is expected your results will improve.

Comment: If I use 12V or 20V battery, Won't it burn the active motor when All other motors are turned off ?

Comment: @Steve Jobs, never dismiss altering the requirements, design or changing even the software for dealing with hardware limitations.  Often we impose impossible requirements or situations upon our selves that are unnecessary to obtain the desired goal. And often hardware problems can be solved in software.

Comment: Its not the voltage you need to change is the Amps (current).  The voltage times the current gives you the wattage (which is a measure of the power).  You can get more power by increasing the voltage, but like you said you'll blow the motors.

Comment: You need to understand the motor specifications.  What the motor expects with respect to voltage and current.  You also need to under stand the (I assume you are using a) Arduino Motor shield.  You can not skip over reading about these things.  And we certainly can not read them to you.

Comment: I am doing this without motor shield,  :P

Comment: If I add a 20V power supply with more than enough Amps ,  And Use resistators to limit current flow,  Can I prevent motor from blowing when other motors are off ? and Also by this way is it possible to provide same power to all motors other motors are on or off ?

Comment: Are the motors  20V motors?

Comment: They are just small dc motors 
You can see a image of the motor from this link http://www.robotshop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/o/solarbotics-regular-motor-2.jpg

Comment: According to [the website](http://www.robotshop.com/en/solarbotics-regular-motor-2.html), the optimal voltage is 4.5V. So you are already overdriving them with you 9V battery. Although that 9 volt will drop quite a bit when the motor is on, as 9V batteries can't provide that much current. I'd suggest getting a [battery pack that can fit 4 AA cells](http://www.robotshop.com/en/battery-holder-4xaa-flat.html).